# biometric chip in UK passport not working

Tags: biometric-passports

Tried to use the egate in the UK but was told my UK Passport chip is not working and had to go through manually. Would this be a problem when entering the US with ESTA?

Has anyone encountered this? Any resolution or is this usually temporary and goes after a while? What could cause this?

Comment: Sometimes this just happens at random. Unless it has happened to you on more than say one quarter of your recent entries I would not worry about it too much.